# Docker postgresql restore back on Windows operating system

Tags: windows, postgresql, docker, restore

On Ubuntu server i use simple line, to restore backup.

```
sudo cat $BACKUPNAME | docker exec -i automation-pg psql -U postgres
```

How to do it in Windows operating system? **cat** dose not work in **CMD**
If i do it in **PowerShell** it throws, "ERROR:  syntax error at or near "pg_dump""

There seems to be plenty help for Unix, but not for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `type test.txt` to read out a file and use the command `echo %variable%` to read out a variable in windows command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

## Backup and Restore via Docker with Docker-Compose in Windows

Docker compose example:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14.4
    container_name: db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgres"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  pgadmin4:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: "user-email"
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: "postgres"
    ports:
      - "15432:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  pgdata:

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: main-network
```

### Backup

```
docker-compose exec -T db pg_dump -U postgres database_name > backup_db.sql
```

### Restore

```
cat .\backup_db.sql | docker-compose exec -T db psql -U postgres -d database_name
```